# Can we have comment templates?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

This question is inspired from this post: [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/28557) in TeX.SX.
Can EE.SE have similar comment templates?

Answer (score 8):

This post is a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/226705) post, so feel free to edit it.

### Useful links

- `[How to Ask](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)-page`
- `[What is on-topic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)-page`
- `[Using MathJax](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/434/27943)`
- `[How do I format my post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)-page`

### New Users

#### Welcome

- `Welcome to EE.SE! Find out everything you need to get started by taking a 2-minute [tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).`

#### Possible duplicates

- For new(ish) users whose question looks like it might get closed as a duplicate:
  `Welcome to EE.SE! This question is very similar to [link]. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.`
- On casting first dupe vote on a question where the OP has not said 'Oh yes, it's a dupe':
  `I've voted to close this as a duplicate because currently, the question looks very similar to [link]. Note that closing a question is not final. If you feel that this question is not a duplicate you can edit it to add more information, in which case it may be reopened.`
- Question cross-posted on another stack:
  `Please don't cross-post.  [StackExchange policy is against cross-posting.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)  For future reference, you can make a flag to the moderators to migrate a question to another stack, if you so choose.`

#### Off-topic

- `This question does not appear to be about electronics design and hence it is likely to be classified as off-topic and removed. Please visit our [What is on-topic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)-page to know more.`
- OP bought undocumented stuff, asks us instead of seller for documentation:
  `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, as StackExchange should not be used as substitute for sufficient documentation. Please refer to the manufacturer, seller or service dealer for sufficient documentation, as is the standard for any reputable business.`

#### Formatting issues

- `Welcome to EE.SE! This question has formatting problems and hence question is likely to be removed if not properly presented. Please see our [How do I format my post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)-page to improve the formatting so that your question is communicated properly.`

#### Migrated posts

- `[Welcome to EE.SE!](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.`

### Answers which don't conform to standards

#### Comment posted as an answer

- `This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).`

#### Question posted as an answer

- `[Welcome to EE.SE!](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)! This is not an answer to the question. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.  Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.`
- `If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.`

#### Link-only answer

- `While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.`

Comment: You can use shortcuts like `[tour]` ([tour]), `[help]` ([help]), `[help/on-topic]` ([help/on-topic]), `[ask]` ([ask]), etc. This is useful in case later the URLs are changed. See http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Boy, it's difficult to resist the urge to edit this post and change the verbatim links into HTML links. There must be a name for that condition :D

Comment: So are you proposing we copy and paste these into questions from here as needed?

Comment: @MattYoung I thought [this script](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) can help with that.

Comment: And that integrates into the Stack?

Answer (score -8):

No, we should not have more comment templates since the templates we do already have are annoying and more trouble than they are worth.  This shouldn't be made worse by adding even more templates.

For a example of a annoying comment template, try voting to close a question for OFF TOPIC > OTHER.  The comment box is seeded with some initial text, which so far has never been exactly what I wanted to say or how I wanted to say it.  Even worse, the seeded text isn't automatically deleted when you start typing with the cursor at the start.  You have to actually select the seeded text and delete it, then type what you intended.  This hassle discourages people from taking the time to explain why exactly they are closing a question.  As a result, I sometimes click on the nearest handy close reason, whether it applies or not.

If more comment templates are implemented, at least don't make them so nanny-ish that you have to delete them first.  You should always be able to just type what you want and ignore any possible templates.  Templates should never be in your face.  They should require a deliberate act to use them if you choose to.

Comment: It really isn't that difficult to get rid of the template text. Just remember to hit control-A before you type your first character, and it will immediately replace the existing text.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks, I didn't know about CTRL-A. I tried it and it worked. The seeded text still feels nanny-ish, and that still causes me to develop a *eh, screw these jerks* attitude towards explaining why I'm voting to close, but your information has helped make it a little less annoying.